# sscanf read till end of the string

Tags: c, scanf

I need to split the string into two part, first column of the string is the first part and rest of the string is the second part. First part needs to be stored in `first_str` and the second part in `rest_str`.

I am using `sscanf` to achieve the result, I managed to get the desired output with the following example when the `sentence[]` does not contains any literal `\n`.

In short, I need to know the the format specifier till the end of the input string. Till now I was able to make it work till `\n` is seen , but cannot use it anymore. Can someone help in reading till the end of string instead of till `\n` is seen.

Here is scaled down example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char sentence []="abc@xyz.com foo bar foobar\nhey there";
  char first_str [200];
  char rest_str [200];

  //sscanf (sentence,"%s %99[^\0]",first_str,rest_str);
  sscanf (sentence,"%s %99[^\n]",first_str,rest_str);

  printf ("first column is %s\nevertyhing else is %s\n",first_str,rest_str);

  return 0;
}
```

Desired result:

```
first column is abc@xyz.com
evertyhing else is foo bar foobar\nhey there
```

OR

```
first column is abc@xyz.com
evertyhing else is foo bar foobar
hey there
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `sscanf` for that. It's more trouble than it's worth it.

Comment: @melpomene any suggestion for alternate approach to divide string into column based. I am missing `awk` here

Comment: @monk Why use C for text processing?

Comment: @melpomene this is part of socket program were input is in key value, key is of one word whereas value is of multiple words. so I need to separate key in one variable and rest as value in other.

Comment: @monk I repeat: Why C?

Comment: I am working in a module which is in C, this change would be tiny part of it.

Comment: I'd probably use a manual loop with `isspace`, or maybe `strspn` / `strcspn`.

Comment: If the input string does not contain `\n` then `%99[^\n]` will read up to the end of the string. I don't see what the problem is – the code works for both situations. Aside: the first `%s` should restrict the input length too.

Comment: @WeatherVane Here, I am assuming that the string does not contains `\n` literal. Question is to find a definitive way to read till end of the string.

Comment: @WeatherVane The problem is that the input does contain newlines, and we want to read them.

Comment: As I wrote, the code works perfectly well when there is no newline in the string, and when there is a newline in the input string, in which case the conversion stops there. If you want to read everything including any newlines, use `%99[]`

Comment: @ user3121023 what is that for?

Comment: @user3121023 yes I see that the empty `%99[]` is a format spec error.

Comment: You could probably do something horrible with `%n%199c%n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sscanf` supports the `%n` format specifier to return the number of consumed characters. You can use it to determine how long of a prefix did `sscanf` consume.

The following code sets `rest_str` to point to "the rest of the string":

```
int main ()
{
  char sentence []="abc@xyz.com foo bar foobar\nhey there";
  char first_str [200];
  char *rest_str;

  int n = 0;
  sscanf (sentence,"%s %n",first_str,&n);
  rest_str = sentence + n;

  printf ("first column is %s\nevertyhing else is %s\n",first_str,rest_str);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never use `strncpy`.

Comment: @melpomene: why not? If you are aware what it does there's no reason not to.

Comment: I strongly disagree. It's either a bug waiting to happen, or a wonky abstraction. Like [`gzgetss`](https://php.net/gzgetss) in PHP it's a function that shouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: @melpomene: well, that's your personal opinion that's not backed by any facts. There are cases where `strncpy` is exactly what is needed for the job (though frankly the 'fill with zeros' behavior isn't required in this example). In either case it's off-topic for this question and this answer.

Comment: Your code happens to work in this example because the `sentence + n` string is shorter than `sizeof rest_str`. If it weren't, this would be an out-of-bounds memory access. In other words, it has exactly the same problems as `strcpy`, but `strcpy` is easier to use.

Comment: I'd sleep better if that `sscanf` had a return value check.

Comment: @melpomene - I would be snoring - if and in addition if the format parameters did not make it possible for a buffer overrun.

Comment: @ybungalobill can you please help me understand what does `rest_str = sentence + n;` does in above example ?

Comment: @monk `n` is the number of characters of the string extracted by `%s`  to `first_str`. So `sentence + n` is a pointer to the beginning of the "rest" of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

1. Find the first occurence of a separator in the string. The separator here is the word separator, a space in your case. But it's easy to expand the algorithm to include tabulation, newlines, form feed character, etc.
2. Print null byte there.
3. First column starts at the beginning of the sentence up until that written null byte. Second column starts after the separator.

Code below produces expected output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char sentence []="abc@xyz.com foo bar foobar\nhey there";

    char *pnt = strpbrk(sentence, " ");
    if (pnt == NULL) {
        printf("first column is %s\n", sentence);
        printf("there is no second column\n");
        return 0;
    }
    *pnt = '\0';
    pnt++;
    // omit multiple spaces
    while (*pnt != '\0' && *pnt == ' ') pnt++;
    if (*pnt == '\0') {
        printf("first column is %s\n", sentence);
        printf("there is was no second column, tho multiple spaces were found\n");
        return 0;
    }

    char *first_str = sentence;
    char *rest_str = pnt;

    printf ("first column is %s\nevertyhing else is %s\n", 
        first_str, 
        rest_str);

    return 0;
}
```